# How to make an image display above the background of an :after element

Tags: html, css, image, css-shapes

Not sure how else to title this (if someone else has a better title feel free to edit the post) but essentially the clients wants responsive aarced lines along the top one pink and one purple as shown here in the screenshot:

[image]

Im currently accomplishing this (since an image is not responsive enough) using the element (pink) a ::before (the purple area) and an ::after (the pink line) Now i need an image slider to peek in below it but currently its being covered by the layers before it:

[image]

it needs to look like this mockup:

[image]

Is there any way i can acomplish this?

html:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container firstbelow"></div>
```

css:

```
    .topbar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5;
}

.topbar:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: -20%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 140%;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgb(250, 244, 255);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 0 / 90%;
    border-top: 5px solid #ff88bb;
    z-index: 5;
}

.topbar:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: -20%;
    top: 42%;
    width: 140%;
    height: 150%;
    background: #8855bb;
    box-shadow: inset 10px -10px 5px -10px #000;
    border-radius: 80% 0 0 0 / 60%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
    z-index: 5;
    }
.firstbelow {
    margin-top: -95px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(../images/slider/Commercial.png);
    z-index: 4
}
```

(Note: Yes, i am aware that the ::after element has a white background. if it does not then the pink and putple layers show through and i still cannot see the slider image)

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need a clip or mask for that. Perhaps consider an SVG or gradeitn solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may also use a container in a `fixed` position and set a `padding-top` or `margin top` to the content that it may also slide underneath.

You can also play with gradient , shadow and radius to draw your shape:
snippet below or **[codepen](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VaEZNm)**

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
header div {
  background: linear-gradient(165deg, #FFC0CB 31%, transparent 31.5%), linear-gradient(175deg, #FFC0CB 41%, transparent 41.5%), linear-gradient(179.5deg, #FFC0CB 32.5%, transparent 33%);
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 220px;
}
header:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 120px;
  margin: -55px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 1500px 0 0 0 / 150px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: inset 50px 80px 0 -70px #FFC0CB, inset 20px 90px 0 -70px #8855BB, inset 30px 80px 0 -50px #FF88BB;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: solid #FFC0CB 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  max-width:100%;
}
nav {
  width: 800px;
  max-width:100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav img {
  border-radius: 50% / 3em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
nav a {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 1em;
  color: gray
}
main {
  padding-top: 160px;
  color: #FF88BB;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px gray;
  text-align: justify
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
pre {
  color: gray;
  display: table;
  border-bottom: solid #FFC0CB;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}
pre {
  background: lightgray;
}
li {
  color: #8855BB
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/100/food/8" />
      </a>
      <span><a href="#"> link</a>
  <a href="#"> link</a>
  <a href="#"> link</a>
  <a href="#"> link</a>
  <a href="#"> link</a>
  <a href="#"> link</a>
  </span>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</main>
```

Comment: this is almost a perfect match for what i needed. modifying it slightly to work here, one thing is im hoping i can make it cut off the bottom of the logo. the girl logo they have needs to cut off with the curve and as of yet i havent found a good way of doing this but im going to keep trying.

Comment: @JLGriffin if you use a png, make it partially transparent : update example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VaEZNm

Answer (score 1):

Put the topbar as an absolute element at the top of the page

```
.topbar {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
    z-index: 5;
    height: <static_dimension>;
}
```